# Geth Console being ridiculous with unlockAccount "Error: invalid argument 2: cannot unmarshal non-string as hex data"

Tags: ethereum

Trying to unlock an account from the console in geth, getting the following responses

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "Password", 1000)

Error: invalid argument 2: cannot unmarshal non-string as hex data

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "Password")

true

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "Password", "0x1000")

unlock duration must be a number

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "Password", 0x1000)

Error: invalid argument 2: cannot unmarshal non-string as hex data

> personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[0], "Password", 5)

Error: invalid argument 2: cannot unmarshal non-string as hex data

Answer (score -2):

Never mind the Go-Etherium Developers broke their own code again.

As of Jan 10/2017

Comment: what do you mean they broke their own code? do you know of the issue causing this error?

Comment: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/3542  They pushed a build for consumption in this case on "apt-get" that didn't work.